# how to bootstrap machines using a local repository for chef-client

Tags: centos, chef-infra

I would need to store chef-client on a local repository (nexus) as rpm and use that when I bootstrap a new node, so the new machine will not download it from chef.io, but from a local server.

Is that possible? How can I do it?

Thank you,
Gabriel

Comment: You can, just use a custom bootstrap template for knife. This is already covered by the [official documentation](https://docs.chef.io/knife_bootstrap.html#custom-templates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of several options:

1. Use `--bootstrap-url` to give a URL to a locally hosted installer script that works similarly to the normal Omnitruck script.
2. Use `--bootstrap-command` give a command to be run instead of the curl-bash.
3. Use a custom bootstrap template. Replace whatever you want.